# Function that handles several go routines doesn't execute expected number of times

Tags: go, goroutine

Here's the function. I would expect that it would spawn noOfLoops*len(objs) go routines, but after few executions the function stops and doesn't even return.

```
func (s *service) DoStuff(ctx context.Context, noOfLoops int) error {
    errChan := make(chan error)

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 1; i <= noOfLoops; i++ {

        offset := 100 * i

        objs, err := s.GetObjs(ctx, offset)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        wg.Add(len(objs))
        for _, svc := range objs {
            srvc := svc

            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()
                
                ... DO STUFF

                if err != nil {
                    errChan <- err
                }
            }()
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()
    err = <-errChan

    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks

*EDIT*

Here's a reproducible small program, It stops after the first 100 calls to Publish, rather it should call 1000

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type Obj struct {
    ID string
}

const limit = 1000

func main() {
    db := InitDb()
    err := DoStuff(context.Background(), db, 10)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // mimics running server
    for {

    }
}

func DoStuff(ctx context.Context, db []Obj, noOfLoops int) error {

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}

    for i := 0; i < noOfLoops; i++ {

        offset := limit * i

        objs, err := GetObjs(ctx, db, offset)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        for _, svc := range objs {
            srvc := svc
            wg.Add(1)
            go func() {
                defer wg.Done()

                err := Publish(ctx, srvc)

                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
            }()
        }
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return nil
}

func InitDb() []Obj {
    var out []Obj

    for i := 0; i < 50000; i++ {
        out = append(out, Obj{
            ID: fmt.Sprintf("%d", i),
        })
    }

    return out
}

// mimics getting paged objects from mongo db
func GetObjs(ctx context.Context, db []Obj, offset int) ([]Obj, error) {
    var out []Obj
    
    for i := offset; i < len(db)-(len(db)-offset-limit); i++ { // 100 is limit
        out = append(out, db[i])
    }

    return out, nil
}

// mimics publish to kafka
func Publish(ctx context.Context, obj Obj) error {
    fmt.Println("publishing", obj.ID)
    return nil
}
```

Comment: If there's an error, the goroutine will be blocked forever because there's nothing receiving from `errChan`. If there's no error, then `<-errChan` will block forever because there's nothing sent.

Comment: makes sense, therefore errChan needs to be passed as an argument and dealt with outside?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, but an argument vs a closure makes no difference when your synchronization logic in wrong (you also only receive one error when there could be `len(objs)` errors). You could buffer the channel, or receive all errors in a loop and close it, or always return a value over the `errChan` and count them, etc.

Comment: Your edit still blocks at `errChan <- err` because you are not receiving from that channel until after all goroutines have returned. It would also always block if you had more than one error because you only receive once.

Comment: I've tried to remove the channel at all (to simplify) and just log the error if it occurs. still, it never completes

Comment: Then please create a [mre] without the other confounding issues. The simple act of `wg.Add`, `defer wg.Done()` and `wg.Wait()` will ensure all goroutines have been called and returned, and your problem is probably elsewhere.

Comment: done! thanks for the help mate I appreciate it

Comment: That isn't a valid program, and aside form the syntax problems is missing basic things like calling `wg.Add`

Comment: forgive me, I must have screwed up while formatting on editing here

Comment: The problem in this example has nothing to do with goroutines, your `GetObjs` condition is `len(db)-(len(db)-100)`, which will always be 100, but you start counting from `offset`.

Comment: Add some debug print statements to see what you're getting: https://go.dev/play/p/d0rkHa_tiCd

Comment: Your latest edit seems to do what you want? Although you changed the numbers to print up to 10000. (helps to removing confusing arithmetic like `len(db)-(len(db)-offset-limit)` when `len(db)-len(db)` is obviously always 0, so you are just looking for `offset+limit`. Also remove the busy `for{}` loop, that is always a programming error and does not simulate anything like a server, and can have other side effects in the runtime)

Comment: Hi Jim, was a long day, turns out the comment you left made me realize (the day after) that the issue was indeed in the offset of the database. Mind this piece of code is barely resembling what the actual code does. In short (in the actual code) publish deletes entries from the database. So as I was forwarding the offset at each loop, I was increasing the offset, but the database kept shrinking, therefore at some point I was returning empty results and it would never create new go routines. Thanks for the insight!